# Conditional Web.config depending on parent Web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

In my app there are is one Web.config in the root folder and another one in a folder below. Depending on the content of the root Web.config I'd like the sub-Web.config to apply different settings, i.e.:

Root Web.config says: "We're in mode A." -> Subfolder Web.config applies the various settings (e.g. `appSettings`, `system.web` elements) for "mode A".

And there is also a "mode B" and "mode C".

Is this somehow possible? In this case Web.config transforms are not suitable, neither any application-level logic (due to how ASP.NET works I specifically need to activate and de-active parts of the subfolder Web.config).